# Cant get the length of my table in java script

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have following HTML code for an table:

```
<div id="table">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>net</th>
      <th class="green">VAT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="red">Lipstick</td>
      <td>€6.58</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="red">Shoelaces</td>
      <td>€7.34</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="apple">Apple</td>
      <td>0.43</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The table is created with tableify.
Now i want to select a row with this function:

```
function selectedRow(){
                
                var index,
                    table = document.getElementById("table");
            
                for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                    {
                         // remove the background from the previous selected row
                        if(typeof index !== "undefined"){
                           table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
                        }
                        console.log(typeof index);
                        // get the selected row index
                        index = this.rowIndex;
                        // add class selected to the row
                        this.classList.toggle("selected");
                        console.log(typeof index);
                     };
                }
                
            }
            selectedRow();
```

Here is the following CSS code so that the the background geht a color:

```
.selected{
  background-color: brown;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Normally should the row, that i selected turn brown, but i get a error, that length can't be read. If i have a normal table without  and >tbody>, the code works.
How can i get the body so that can i read the length and the row?

Comment: the code you shared won't work at all because the table has no id but you are using `table = document.getElementById("table");` ... anyway the length will be 4 because it takes into account the header too. Said that, your code is mostly working changing the background color of the clicked row

Comment: Hello Diego, i edited the question, because i forgot something.Know i hope it is clear.

Comment: You've put the `id` on the `<div>`. It should be on the `<table>` instead.

Comment: yeah because tableify give the table no id. So i need another way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you updated the question you added a parent div to fetch the child table. So the selector in that case should be: `#table > table`

Here's a code that achieves that same result in a better way and using `addEventListener` instead of the `onclick` property.

Two strategies are shown to listen for the click event:

- Having a click event handler for each row
- Having a click event handler for the whole table

The first one just listen for the click event for any single row in the table and will check if the table has any selected row before attempting to toggle the class or if the clicked row is the one having the selected class.

The second has one listener for the click event on the table only. Since the event bubble starting from the exact child element clicked (a td for example) it will trigger anyway but it needs to make further checks to better target the context.

## In the end...

I left the first strategy cabled with the logics and made it more narrow so that you can select any row at any moment and it will become the only selected row in the table

```js
addClickEventToTableRows();

//adds a click event handler to the table
function addClickEventToTable(){  
  const table = document.querySelector("#table table");   
  table.addEventListener('click', tableOnClick);
}

//the click event handler for the table
function tableOnClick(event){      
    const clickedElement = event.target;    
    const hasTbodyAsParent = clickedElement.closest('tbody') !== null;
    //if the child element clicked of the table, is a child of tbody
    if ( hasTbodyAsParent ){
      //the clickedrow taken with .closest (since clickedElement could be a td)
      const clickedRow = clickedElement.closest('tr');
      clickedRow.classList.toggle("selected");
      clickedRow.closest('table').removeEventListener('click', tableOnClick);
    }    
}

//adds a click event handler to all the rows of the table
function addClickEventToTableRows(){
  //the table element
  const table = document.querySelector("#table table");  
  //foreach row element in the tbody of the currently selected table
  table.querySelectorAll(':scope > tbody > tr')
    .forEach(row => {
      //add a click event listener to the current row
      row.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        //retrieves the clicked table row
        const clickedRow = event.currentTarget; 
        console.log(`Row: ${clickedRow.rowIndex} was clicked`);
        //if there's not any row in the table with the 'selected' class OR this row has the class selected        
        //if(!clickedRow.closest('tbody').querySelector('.selected') || clickedRow.classList.contains('selected'))
        table.querySelectorAll(':scope > tbody > tr.selected').forEach(trSelected => {
          trSelected.classList.remove('selected');
        });
        //toggle its selected class
        clickedRow.classList.toggle("selected");        
      });
    });
}
```

```css
#table > table > tbody > tr{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#table > table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#table > table > tbody td{
  border: solid 1px lightgray;  
  padding: 1rem;
}

#table > table > thead th{
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.selected {
  background-color: brown;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>net</th>
        <th class="green">VAT</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="red">Lipstick</td>
        <td>€6.58</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="red">Shoelaces</td>
        <td>€7.34</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="apple">Apple</td>
        <td>0.43</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Diego, but how can i achieve it, that i can only select one row. In your code i can select multiple rows.

Comment: to be fair your question didn't involve that requirement that you are adding now. Plus it's not clear what you meant.. if you meant that only one row can be selected at a given time but you can still deselect a row and select another one. Or if you meant that after you selected the row you can't change the selection anymore

Comment: Yeah, sry that it was unclear. I meant, what you wrote first. That you can select only one row and still can deselect a row and select another row.

Comment: anyway I implemented the demo like that already... so that you can select only one row at a given time (and deselect alaso)

Comment: Ah okay i saw what you did there. Thanks for that. Now i must deselect the current row, when i click on another row. So that when one is selected and i click another one, that it deselected automatically the old one and select the new one. But i think i can find that out my myself.

Comment: to deselect you have to click on the selected row. Anyway if the requirement was: deslect the selected row when you select another row.. it was clear enough to understand. but you didn't

Comment: yeah my englisch is not so good :D